# How can I keep the Knights Templar alive throughout the medieval period?

Tags: society, religion, geopolitics

The Adeptus Sororitas was an independent organization of exclusively Catholic women that focused on caring for the sick and dying in war-ravaged Europe during the medieval period.

They were founded in 1119 and recognized by the Papal Bull in 1139. The organization established a number of orders around the continent, and became known throughout as kind, merciful caretakers that provided assistance and care to Christian pilgrims in need. This eventually culminated in the purchase of land in their many locations, and the organization grew exceedingly wealthy and famous. During this time however, strange and supernatural events began happening wherever the sisters operated. These events were spontaneous and were not controlled by these individuals. Although the sisters could not just call upon these supernatural effects by will, they soon became associated with the orders, with one eventually morphing into a group of warrior nuns known as the "Knights Templar".

This order is the military branch of the organization in which women take up arms and fight in wars on behalf of the Church against God's enemies, such as the Crusades. Those supernatural events, now called "miracles" became synonymous with this order, and often occurred at inopportune times whenever they entered the battlefield. Raising of dead allies, shield of protection against friendly forces, and other manifestations helped secure victory on many fronts.

For many, it was as if these sisters, as well as their parent organization, had been chosen by God himself as the worthiest of his servants. However, no matter how useful or faithful this organization was, they would always be viewed as a threat by those in power due to their influence and wealth.

There are three scenarios I can foresee happening here:

1. As the Messiah was male and capable of performing miracles, the establishment may view them eventually as performing witchery or sorcery. The orders would be associated with the devil Baphomet and burned at the stake.
2. As they are so powerful and widespread, they may eventually rival the church in power and pose a threat, hence leading them to be associated with witchcraft and sorcery, and burned at the stake.
3. An opportunistic king, heavy in debt and wanting to exploit the resources that the orders have gained over the years, would pressure the Pope to declare them as heretics who get their powers from the devil. They would be associated with witchcraft and sorcery, and hence burned at the stake.

Neither of these scenarios end well for the Knights Templar, but they seem inevitable with all the politicking and backstabbing and family squabbles made infamous by Medieval Europe. How can this organization avoid this terrible fate so that it can survive into the 21st century?

Comment: The words *Adeptus* and *Sororitas* do not go together... You may want *Adepta sororitas*. (Abstracts in *-tas*, *-tatis* are invariably feminine: *ebrietas*, *felicitas*, *pietas*, *veritas*.) (That is, unless the imaginary world where the Knightesses Templar are an offshoot of a female order also has an imaginary Latin language.)

Comment: So ... do they have magic?

Comment: @Halfthawed magical events happen around them, but they are not called upon or controlled. They are spontaneous miracles, but righteous and virtuous .

Comment: Your question is very confusing, since the Knights Templar was an actual organization having little resemblence to what you describe.

Comment: Change the name to *The Red Cross*, open lodges and continue to charge six million people 'dues' so that they can call themselves masons.

Comment: @AlexP: The faux Latin almost surely comes from the Warhammer 40,000 game universe; the use case there is 100% based on the Rule of Cool, rather than the rules of Latin grammar.

Comment: @sharur: AFAIK, Warhammer 40,000 features the grammatically correct form [*Adepta sororitas*](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Adepta_Sororitas). The mangling belongs entirely to the querent. (Warhammer 40,000 originates in the United Kingdom; we take our Latin seriously in Europe.)

Comment: @AlexP They used to be called Adeptus Sororitas in older publications. This followed a common theme. Most government organizations of the Imperium of Man are named Adeptus Something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When king [Louis IX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_IX_of_France) died (in 1270), he left several children, of which the oldest was princess [Isabella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabella_of_France,_Queen_of_Navarre). Her brother prince [Philip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_III_of_France) contested Isabella's inheritance of the throne, but the Council of State, dominated by the Grandes Seigneuresses, many of whom were lay members or supporters of the Sororitas Adepta, rejected the [Salic Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salic_law) and upheld a less known provision of the less known [Ripuarian Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_Ripuaria), which stated that the Crown of France was an [allodial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allod) title, and, as a consequence, could be inherited by heirs of both sexes, in order of primogeniture.

Princess Isabella, which at that time was Queen consort of [Navarre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Navarre), was crowned Queen of France. As in real history, she accompanied her husband [Theobald II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theobald_II_of_Navarre) of Navarre and her father in the Eighth Crusade; the husband and the father having both died obligingly in 1270 (actually true) she became Queen regnant of both France and Navarre, bringing about the union of the two kingdoms  several centuries ahead of schedule.

Queen Isabella promoted the Grand Mistress of the Knightesses Templar, Jacqueline de Molay ($\leftarrow$ pun), to the dignity of Adaptress of France, transforming the kingdom in the world's first magically woke medieval polity, of which the motto was *Liberté, Égalité, Sororité*. Drawing on the sorcerous abilities of the more Illuminated sisters in the Sororitas Adepta, she proceeded to lengthen her rule past her historically fated death in 1271, turning the first page in the enchanted *her*story which would, in the fullness of time, see the advent of the proclamation of the [*Déclaration des droits de la Femme et de la Citoyenne*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9claration_des_droits_de_la_femme_et_de_la_citoyenne), of which [article the first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_of_the_Rights_of_Man_and_of_the_Citizen#Articles) clearly stated that all men are born and remain free and equal in rights, but women are more equal than men.

Ensconced within the [natural frontiers of the rich and sweet France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_borders_of_France), the Sororitas Adepta found itself in the enviable position of holding an unassailable preeminence over rival orders; soon, anti-popess Joan II, ruling ex cathedra from the [City of Light](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/City_of_Light), reformed the Holy Trinity into the symbolically definitive [Persons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostasis_(philosophy_and_religion)) of God the Mother, God the Father and God the Son, with a Mariology paralleling the Christology into designating Mary in her capacity as Mother of God as the [same in essence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoousion) with the Father.

Once this threshold had been reached, with a novel and all-ecompassing intersectionalist interpretation of Christianity established in the richest and most powerful kingdom of western Europe, the survival and prosperity of the Sorority could no longer be put in question.

Today, the Sorority dominates European finance (through its banking branch, the [Sororité Générale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_G%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale)), European entertainment industry (ruled with an iron fist in a velvet glove by the [Générale des Eaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivendi)), European defense industry (through D'Assaulte), European automotive industry (through Renaulte) and so on.

Comment: This is awesome!  Especially the implication that the Adaptress might still be alive.  But I do not get the pun.

Comment: @Willk: The last Grand Master of the real Knights Templar was [Jacques de Molay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_de_Molay). Burned at the stake on 18 March 1314, as a relapsed heretic, because he retracted the confessions he had made under torture and reaffirmed the purity and holiness of the Order.

Answer (score 4):

They need their own territory to occupy free of harassment and they need powerful allies - possibly one of the branches of the Catholic Church, Protestant reformers, or an antipope.

See the Knights of Malta - one of the Oldest Knight Orders that still retain much of their sovereignty even in present day

Comment: Basically they need either to be a lot more powerful or to be a less tempting target. Being a rich, supra-national organization in Paris when the King of France needs money tends not to end well.

Comment: They themselves don't have to be. But it helps if they don't physically co-inhabit a space with their enemy, and have some backers with a vested interest in keeping them around

Comment: @knowads "don't physically co-inhabit a space with their enemy" - do you have the Teutonic Order in mind when you say this? Lasted well into the 16th century, and had they not been right next to Poland, could have easily lasted until the unification of Germany or even beyond.

Comment: @MichaelW. Yes the Teutonic Order is a great example. The closer the Knight Order operates as its own sovereign nation-state the better it will be - even the Crusader Kingdoms survived longer than they should have.

Answer (score 1):

If this order is effectively possesses magic, they need to have this magic to be seen as the Grace of God, and by no means as a witchcraft.

If the nuns and and entire Order are seen as not just devout, but favored by God, then any move against it would be blasphemous. Monarchs and the Pope might go to great lengths trying to control the order, but they, as good Christians, would never risk moving directly against it.

Having said that, there would always be a suspicion that the Order's magic is a work of Devil. This belief can cause significant tension withing the Church, and can even cause its splintering. In this scenario, one (or more) monarch can outlaw the Order, setting him/herself up against the Pope and other monarchs. The splintered group can launch a "holy war" against the Order, and may even prevail in it. This risk is inherent, because Order's job is magic, and some people would always be skeptical about it. The Order can lower this risk by maintaining good relationship with every country (though this may be easier said than done).

Answer (score 1):

According to various "alt history" books ad websites, the remaining members of the "*Poor Fellow-Soldiers of Christ and of the Temple of Solomon*" somehow managed to escape with their fleet after the Order was condemned and their Grand Master and many senior people captured, tortured and burned as heretics. They are variously said to have fled to Scotland or the New World, and transformed themselves from a monastic fighting order into the Freemasons. Speculation about their demise has been aided by factual mysteries like the inability of anyone to find the Templar treasure or the fate of the Templar fleet, to bizarre speculations about places like the [Rosslyn Chapel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosslyn_Chapel) and the [Oak Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_Island) "treasure pit".

While the OP suggests the Templars in this scenario are under extreme peril like the *Poor Fellow-Soldiers of Christ and of the Temple of Solomon* in OTL, there are some elements of the "alt history" version of the story which might work well in maintaining the Templars as a force in modern society in the OP's timeline.

In OTL, the Templars had a vast network of correspondents and carried out banking operations on a continental scale across Europe and parts of the Middle East. The reason no one found their treasure is they were looking for the wrong things. Kings, nobles and other avaricious people looking to seize the treasure were expecting chests of gold. OTL Templars may have invented a form of double entry book keeping and their "treasure" was recorded in ledger books rather than piles of coins. If the OP's Templars had done something similar, then they would have both access to huge amounts of wealth, the ability to manipulate people, guilds and kingdoms to their benefit and be able to do so in ways no one could understand or replicate for at least 300 years (the arrival of "modern" banking). By that time, members of the order would have been in positions of power and influence for centuries, and could simply insinuate themselves into the system as the oldest and most powerful banking syndicate in the world.

As time passes, the requirement for fighting monks (or sisters) would also change. The OTL Templars are supposed to have taken their military skills and modified them to become leaders in other aspects of society as Freemasons, there is no reason the Templars in the OP's setup could not do the same either covertly or overtly. The Grandmistress could devote more time and attention to secular rather than military activities (even moving stepwise, such as establishing military academies and them branching into schools of higher learning while gradually withdrawing from the fighting roles), and the Order gradually follows suit. Templars and graduates from Templar academies become the leaders of industry, finance, commerce, academia and government, as well as high ranking officers in military staffs, and certainly anyone looking for high level help in any of these fields would seek out a Templar or graduate of a Templar school.

So the Templars don;t have to be overtly militaristic, and indeed their roles and contributions should change and evolve with the rest of the world in order to remain relevant. The *Knights Hospitaller* no longer go around armed "cap-a-pie", and indeed if they were to do so today it would be considered extremely unsettling. Outside of historical reenactment it would have no true purpose (even the Pope's Swiss Guards are actually armed and equipped like modern light infantry, the ones you see in St Peter's Square are a ceremonial unit: https://www.guns.com/news/2017/04/16/guns-swiss-guard)

So all that really needs to happen is the Templars evolve with the times, find useful niches to occupy and leverage their wealth and knowledge to remain close to the centres of power. Any "magic" that they have can be considered a bonus, and not even needed to remain a relevant part of modern society.

Answer (score 0):

If god is on their side — as appears to be the case — then they don’t have much to fear.

Alternatively, they could go underground as the real Knights Templar are alleged to have done.